# map: can't zoom in current location

Tags: ios, objective-c, location, mkmapview, cllocationmanager

**Issue**: Map doesn't zoom in on the user's current location when the map is first loaded.

I'm trying to understand what I am doing wrong here. As you can tell, I'm quite new to this so please be kind :)

.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

@interface MapViewController : UIViewController<MKMapViewDelegate>
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet MKMapView *shopMapView;
@property (retain, nonatomic) CLLocationManager *locationManager;

@end
```

.m

```
#import "MapViewController.h"
#import "ShopModel.h"
#import "ShopAnnotation.h"
#import "ShopAnnotationView.h"
#import "CoordinatingController.h"



@interface MapViewController ()

@end

@implementation MapViewController
@synthesize shopMapView;
@synthesize locationManager;

#pragma mark - Helper methods -

-(void) resetAllAnnotations
{
    // code for resetting all annotations on the map
}

-(void) findLocation
{
    NSString *city = [ [ ShopModel sharedInstance ] userSelectedCity ];

    if ( city == nil )
        return;

    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[ NSAutoreleasePool alloc ] init ];
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=%@&output=csv", 
                           [ city stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    NSString *locationString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString] encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error ];
    NSArray *listItems = [locationString componentsSeparatedByString:@","];

    double latitude;
    double longitude;

    if([listItems count] >= 4 && [[listItems objectAtIndex:0] isEqualToString:@"200"]) {
        latitude = [[listItems objectAtIndex:2] doubleValue];
        longitude = [[listItems objectAtIndex:3] doubleValue];
    }
    else {
        // errors
    }

    CLLocation *location = [[ CLLocation alloc ] initWithLatitude: latitude longitude: longitude ];

    [ self performSelectorOnMainThread: @selector( zoomInLocation: ) withObject:  location  waitUntilDone: NO ];
    [ location release ];
    [ pool release ];
}

-(void) zoomInLocation: ( CLLocation * ) location
{
    shopMapView.region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(  location.coordinate, 800,800 );
}

#pragma mark - MapViewDelegate -

-(MKAnnotationView*) mapView:(MKMapView *)shopMapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    ShopAnnotationView *view = ( ShopAnnotationView *) [ shopMapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier: @"Test" ];

    if ( view == NULL )
    {
        view = [ [[ ShopAnnotationView alloc ] initWithAnnotation: annotation reuseIdentifier: @"Test" ] autorelease ];
        [ view setCanShowCallout: YES ];
        view.rightCalloutAccessoryView = [ UIButton buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure ];
    }

    return view;
}

-(void) mapView:(MKMapView *)shopMapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control
{
    [ [ CoordinatingController sharedInstance ] requestViewChangeByObject: view ];
}

-(void) changeCity
{
    [ self performSelectorInBackground: @selector( findLocation ) withObject: nil ];

}

#pragma mark - ViewController life cycle -

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {}

    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.navigationItem.title = NSLocalizedString( @"Map", @"Map" );

    [ self performSelectorInBackground: @selector( findLocation ) withObject: nil ];
    [ self resetAllAnnotations ];

    [ [ NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter ] addObserver: self selector: @selector( resetAllAnnotations ) name: @"AllAnnotationsUpdated" object: nil ];

    [ [ NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter ] addObserver: self selector: @selector( changeCity ) name: @"CityChanged" object: nil ];

}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [self setMapView:nil];
    [super viewDidUnload];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

- (void)dealloc {

    [ [ NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter ] removeObserver: self ];
    [shopMapView release];
    [super dealloc];
}
@end
```

Comment: Question says map should zoom to "user's current location" but the code in findLocation sets `location` to some values returned from a Google api query.  Put NSLogs in findLocation to print out values that are returned and to confirm the code is doing what you think it should.  Also suggest stepping through that code in the debugger.  Also confirm that findInLocation and zoomInLocation actually execute.  In zoomInLocation, NSLog the coordinate values.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is a type here on StackOverflow, but in your code I see that the zoom method starts with a uppercase, and you are calling it with a lowercase.
I suggest renaming the zoom method like this:

```
-(void) zoomInLocation: ( CLLocation * ) location
{
    shopMapView.region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(  location.coordinate, 800,800 );
}
```

Comment: No, this was only here on SO.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem in an app I wrote. My MKMapView started off in the Atlantic Ocean, off the coast of Africa, which is (0,0) in Latitude and Longitude. Try inserting this where you need to get the location of the user:

```
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{


       int timeout = 10000000;

       while (self.mapView.userLocation.location == nil && timeout > 0) {

          sleep(1);
          timeout--;
    }

    //do whatever you need to do once you have the user's location. 
    [self findLocation];
});
```

This waits until it finds the location of the user, then does what you need to do. It isn't on the main thread, so it won't freeze the UI up.

Comment: Interesting, Where do you put this logic in your code though? viewDidLoad?

Comment: Yeah that's where I have it.